# Правильно ли созданная контекстно-свободная грамматика для sql запроса select?

Tags: sql, c, компилятор

Вот данная грамматика:

```
 query -> "select" all | select_result "from" table_refs where_clause
   all -> "*"
   select_result -> col_refs | agg
   agg -> agg_func (col_refs)
   agg_func -> MIN | MAX | COUNT
   col_refs -> col_ref, col_refs | col_ref
   table_refs -> table_name, table_refs | table_name
   where_clause -> "where" var opt value
   var -> col_ref
   opt -> > | < | >= | <= | =
   value -> [a-zA-Z] | [a-zA-Z] value | [0-9] | [0-9] value
```

Я хочу узнать, правильно ли оформлена грамматика для ll парсера, и если нет, то почему и где я мог ошибиться. Заранее спасибо )

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Это русский раздел SO, тут нужно на русском вопросы писать )

Comment: Моя ошибка, не увидел )

Comment: Ну в общем или переводите вопрос, или его закроют, такие правила )